# Azure Traffic Manager Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-traffic-manager

I have two web apps deployed on cloud services in two regions.

- WebApp1.cloudapp.net
- WebApp2.cloudapp.net

I created Azure Traffic Manager with Performance Load Balancing

- WebApp.trafficmanager.net

What is CName for my cloud app and how can I configure this CName point to Azure Traffic Manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CNAME for your app is WebApp.trafficmanager.net. You will need to register a custom domain from one of the DNS providers -- once done use the tools they provide to add a CNAME record for "www" to your domain and point it at your Traffic Manager.

At the moment Azure Traffic Manager does not support apex (naked) domains. So this solution would cover www.yourdomain.com, but not simply yourdomain.com.

Some DNS providers support forwarding where you can specify yourdomain.com should redirect to www.yourdomain.com.

If this is not the case, you can enable forwarding in your Azure Web App by adding this to your web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Apex Redirection" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:2}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Then you would pick either of your cloud service regions and grab the "A" record from the Azure management console for your DNS record. Anyone who goes to yourdomain.com would go to that region's app and get redirected to your Traffic Manager at www.yourdomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

You would register a custom domain name with the registrar of your choice (ie. GoDaddy, Network Solutions, etc).  Once you have this domain name you would then configure it on the registrar's site to have a CNAME entry pointing to the trafficmanager.net address.  So it would look like:
   www.webapp.com IN CNAME webapp.trafficmanager.net